# XCode 4.3 partially forbid navigation in a tableview using storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tableview

I'm creating an iPhone app using storyboard. I have a table view and 4 sections. Now I try to forbid the navigation in section 3 and 4 to the detail because the values in this section are calculated values which comes from the values in section 1 and 2.

What can I do? I tried to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to do this but unfortunately the detail view is called in each case. Thanks a lot for each hint to everyone.

Comment: You don't say **how** the detail is presented.  Do you have a segue directly from the table view cell to the detail controller?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Yes there is a modal segue from the cell to the detail controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the source of your segue to be the view controller that contains the table instead of the table view cell, then you can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` as a place to decide whether or not to advance to the detail controller.  In the sections where you **do** want a detail, you would use a call to `performSegueWithIdentifier:` to trigger it.

Comment: Hmmm, I created a smaller example with two sections of a table which is part of my root view controller. I implemented the segue from my cell to the detail view in IB and implemented `didSelectRowAtIndextPath:` that I only call `performSegueWithIdentifier` if I select a row of section **0**. But I can a also navigate to the detail view when I click on a cell in section **1**.

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CarDetailViewController *detailController;
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        [detailController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCarDetails" sender:self];
    }
}`

Comment: If I read that right, you missed the part about making the segue from the controller rather than from the cell.

Comment: great! Thats exactly what I want! Thanks a lot.